# How to convert a image file to PDF file in php?

Tags: php, pdf

I was working on a light PHP project where I need to convert all user image file to PDF file and I need a simple solution for convert the image

```
foreach ($result as $information) {
            $count++;
            $file = $information->{'patient_prescription'};
            *Image Convert To PDF*
            $success = $img->writeImage('image/patient_prescription_picture/pdf/' . $count . 'pdf');
            $fileArray[$count] = 'image/patient_prescription_picture/pdf/' . $count . 'pdf';

        }
```

Comment: So, show the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
foreach ($result as $information) {
                $count++;
                $file = $information->{'patient_prescription'};
                $img = new Imagick($file);
                $img->setImageFormat('pdf');
                $success = $img->writeImage('image/patient_prescription_picture/pdf/' . $count . 'pdf');
                $fileArray[$count] = 'image/patient_prescription_picture/pdf/' . $count . 'pdf';
}
```